# Can the self keyword in python be overwritten, to a user set term

Tags: python, oop, reference, keyword, self

Title, basically I am having an argument with my friend, in regards to this question, in a homework task

**Question starts here**

Which of the following will the python interpreter accept as the name for the first parameter of instance methods in classes? • (A) self (B) this . (C) thing . (D) all of the above

What would the correct answer be.

Comment: What does your course material say?

Comment: This is easily tested: try a different name and see what happens.

Comment: The correct answer is D.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is D - self is not a magical keyword, but just the conventional name for the first argument in a non-static and non-class method. When you define a method in python, despite the definition looking exactly like a function's, is is wrapped into a special object that, when called, passes given arguments to your function, prepended by a reference to the parental object